# Divs with same id error

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="tagTree1" class="span-6 border"  style='width:280px;height:400px;overflow:auto;float:left;margin:10px; '>
    <a class="tabheader" style="font-size:large">Data Type</a><br />
    <div class="pane">Refine search by Data Type</div>
</div>
```

Above div(tagTree1) is present in a division ad.

```
<div id="newtagTree1" class="span-6 border"  style='width:200px;height:400px;overflow:auto;float:left'>
    <a class="tabheader"><strong>Geographic Location</strong></a><br />
    <div class="pane"><strong>Refine search by geographic location</strong></div>
</div>
```

newTagTree1 division is present in another division search. But both have the same functionality to generate children divisions within them, which is written in a js file. All the children  division generated dynamically in js file. Both of them uses same function to generate children divs. I am facing problem when i am using them in same page. If one works fine then the other doesn't. Can any one say me about the mistake i am doing in this?

Thanks in advance.

```
$.getJSON('/api/TagsApi/Children?id=800002', function (data) {
    //$(tagDiv).empty();

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $("#tagTree1").append(tagTabBuilder(item));
    });

    $("#tagTree1").tabs("#tagTree1 div.pane", { api: true, tabs: 'a', effect: 'slide', onClick: buildChildren, initialIndex: 0 });
});


function tagTabBuilder(tagData) {
    var str = "<input type='checkbox' name='tagchkbox[]' value='" + tagData.ID + "' onClick='startQuery()' /><a class='tabheader '>" + tagData.NAME;

    if (tagData.count == 0) {
        str += " (<span class='el_count' id='t" + tagData.ID + "'>" + tagData.count + "</span>)" + "</a><br/>";
    } else {
        str += " (<span class='el_count' id='t" + tagData.ID + "'><strong>" + tagData.count + "</strong></span>)" + "</a><br/>";
    }
    str += "<div id='tid-" + tagData.ID + "' class='pane tag'><!--Loading subtags. . .<img src='/assets/modules/gaiaModule/shared/images/load-small.gif' />--></div>";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Provide the code of your functions, please.

Comment: @MCL Is that what you want??

Comment: I'm still missing your `buildChildren()`  function. Also, you could indent the code in function bodies.

Comment: I am sorry MCL its a very lengthy code and even buildchildren calls two more functions. I really appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that when they generate child divs, they're generating them with the same ID scheme.  Thus, either of them can generate child divs just fine by itself, but when both of them are included, there is ID collision.  The answer is to modify the child generation code to, for example, include the id of the parent div as the first portion of the id of the child div.

Alternately, if you dont' need them for other portions of the javascript, leave the child div ids out entirely.  In general, I find that it's better to avoid the id attribute in generated nodes, and instead use classes or the like.

Comment: but i need the id of the children divs to be what it is for both ad and search divs. I need them to retrieve data from database using those ids. Is there any other option?

Comment: Yes.  Store it in something other than the id attribute.  The id attribute is special.  It is optimized for finding a node quickly on the page, but it is unique - which means that you're simply not allowed to have two nodes on the same page with the same id.  No other attribute is unique in the same way.  You can use class if you like, or even just pick a new attribute name, and use that (it makes it a bit more awkward to access, but not all that much, and it makes sure that it wont' interfere with anything else)

Comment: I think using the `class` to store custom data isn't a good practice either. You could define an attribute like `data-id`. Anyway, if the data is always the same, why store it in each child? Why not just once in their parent?

Comment: The data isn't always the same.  Each of the child divs has a different ID.  The problem is that the whole list shows up once in `tagTree1`, and once in `newTagTree1`.  Thus, the collision.  Whether or not it's a good idea to store it in `class` tends to depend on what kind of data it is.  In this case, I would tend to agree with you, but the OP might wish to go with the slightly easier, slightly uglier way.

Comment: @BenBarden I got it now, that's what you get for skimming the posts ;) I certainly don't think it's harder to define data attributes rather than a class. Especially jQuery supports easy access to those with `$.data()`

Comment: hey between can you say me a way on how to kill one division in html?

Comment: I would like to first populate search div with children and on completing the search functionality  i go for ad division to perform some adding stuff.. i dont need search div anymore. I will slide it down to disappear but it is not going to solve my problem ryt? can i destroy it and then populate ad div then?

Comment: @MCL huh.  Cool.  I'd never run into `$.data()` before.  It wasn't so much the defining, though - the OP's running it by building HTML with string manipulation, so building them isn't any harder or easier no matter how it's done.  I was more thinking of the annoyance of dealing with the attr selector and the like, as compared to the relative ease of using the class tools.

Comment: If you want to get rid of divs, you're probably better off working with jquery.  `$.remove()` (http://api.jquery.com/remove/) should get you where you're going once you have the right bit selected.

Comment: however... you really are better off learning how to put the information in a non-id attr of some sort, rather than nuking chunks out of your page.  It'll make the whole thing that much more flexible for later changes.